# Keep csv feature labels for LDA pca

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pca

I am trying to use the 2000 topics' top 20 frequency data at https://github.com/wwbp/facebook_topics/tree/master/csv

I would like to perform randomizedPCA on the data. From the documentation, X needs to be  array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features) .

I have imported the file with `LDA_topics = pd.read_csv(r'2000topics.top20freqs.keys.csv', header=None, index_col=0, error_bad_lines=False)`

however this is not the right format for the following line:

```
pca2 = sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA(n_components=45)
pca2.fit(LDA_topics)
```

resulting in a ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'sonic'

Is there a way to perform PCA and retain the feature labels and not just frequencies afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

PCA doesn't discard or retain features, but the component results don't map to features either. (Given `x`, `y`, `z` and an `n_components=2` param, the resulting two components won't map to any of `xyz` perfectly.) If you want to retain the feature names as part of dimensionality reduction, you might want to explore other approaches ([sklearn has a whole section for this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#feature-selection)).

Chuck Ivan is correct that an encoder or vectorizer is called for before you can do PCA. I like his OrdinalEncoder suggestion, but you may also consider the sklearn text utilities on this list: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction.text

Comment: @ChuckIvan Also consider that with sklearn.pipeline you can (pretty easily) integrate text encoders from popular NLP libraries and NN libraries (keras, nltk, spaCy, et cetera). Happy nlp-ing

Answer (score 1):

PCA works by solving an optimization problem that requires your features to be numeric. This code is trying to perform PCA on non-numeric data. You will need to factorize (encode) the strings into numbers. [sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) and [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) handle that.

Charles Landau's feature extraction solution looks very relevant to the question.