# read only odd-numbered/numeric columns with read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Following up on [Keep csv feature labels for LDA pca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661114/keep-csv-feature-labels-for-lda-pca) I decided to ignore feature names for my PCA reduction. I am using pandas read_csv() function and would like to ignore string/text columns, which happen to be every odd-numbered column. So either a filter to remove string columns or odd-number columns when reading in my csv would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to read column labels and then take every second column via the `usecols` parameter of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). This assumes your column labels are unique, but will be efficient as you are not reading expensive `object` dtype series.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

x = """some,header,labels,for,each,column
1,hello,2,test,3,another
4,another,5,test,6,row
7,and,8,one,9,more"""

# get column names, replace StringIO(x) with 'file.csv'
df_cols = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), nrows=0).columns

# skip even columns, replace StringIO(x) with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), usecols=df_cols[::2])

print(df)

   some  labels  each
0     1       2     3
1     4       5     6
2     7       8     9
```